# Impossible to see CKeditor in production

Tags: ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I have a rails 4 app that use CKeditor. In dev mode it works fine but in production ckeditor does not apear and there is a blank space at the location of the textarea.

According to the logs, the following file is missing :

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/ckeditor/styles.js")
```

And if i precompile the asset i can see the following file generated :

```
public/assets/ckeditor/styles-65fee53acf063b3d207bc00b4f7ce0d5.js
```

Here is the ckeditor line of my application.rb :

```
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
```

It seems that's the file CKeditor want but it is not looking for the precompiled one. How can i fix that?

Comment: Any luck with fixing this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Running into the same issue, whether I use the gem or the javascript download directly.

Comment: Same f problem here..

Comment: got any luck about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

i have pre-compiled my assets and pushed my repo to production server and got similar bug. And ckeditor was not loading.

Following worked for me:

1) Under config > environment > productio.rb file there is a line 
    config.assets.compile = false

i changed false to true and pushed the code to production site. Stopped and started unicorn. That did the trick now ckeditor is loading.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5 you have use in Gemfile 
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'

look here:
https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/719

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow these steps in the Readme? https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#usage-with-rails-4-assets

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the CKEditor BasePath in the `<head>` section of my `application.html.erb` file fixed my issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i had included config.assets.compile = true and didn´t work...

Finally i did rake

```
rake assets:precompile
```

from the console.

If you are uploading images directly to AWS S3 you need to comment out the carrierwave or paperclip initializer while precompiling.

Then pushed it to production and worked fine!